# Is it possible to activate a class for an individual v-bind without triggering others?[VueJS / Laravel]

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple inputs that have a class bound which is triggered if less than 0. All inputs are similar to the one below. My issue is when one the target input is triggered, all inputs with this class bound are triggered instead of just the one. What's the best way to handle this? All inputs are bound to a single variable not shared by any other input. Thanks!

```
<td>
    <input type="number" v-bind:class="{ negative: isNegative }" 
    v-model="totalNetProfit">{{ totalNetProfitCalculation() }}
</td>

totalNetProfitCalculation() {
    this.totalNetProfit = this.totalLotRevenue - this.totalLotCost;
        if (this.totalNetProfit < 0) {
            this.isNegative = true; 
        }
    },
```

Comment: `td` so? there is a `v-for` or something which you are using for making this table ?

Comment: the table is filled with static data. it's a table mostly for aesthetic purposes grouping related inputs together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `name` attribute to all of your `input`s, you could keep an `array` where `key`s are all the input's name attribute.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rabi50/3s50vL3r/1/)

** I wanted to post this as a comment as I am not sure if this is what you wanted, But I don't have points for that.

** [Documentation Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)

Comment: so the name tag can be added to any number of elements, they just need different ids or groups of ids?

Comment: I guess, they just need different names. No need of ids or class unless you need them for some other purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the name attribute.